# SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax when running syncdb on django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to install a django-cms variant (wagtail) and get everything working up until I am doing the './manage.py syncdb'. At that point I get the traceback as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    mod = import_module(app)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/src/wagtail/wagtail/wagtailsearch/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from indexed import Indexed
  File "/opt/software/virt_env/virt1/src/wagtail/wagtail/wagtailsearch/indexed.py", line 43
    indexed_fields = {field: dict(type="string") for field in indexed_fields}
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Seems like the for loop syntax is okay...any ideas? Or was there a massive change in syntax between python 2.6.6 and python27?

I am running PYTHON 2.6.6 and DJANGO 1.6.1 running on RHEL 6.4 (2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64), postgres 8.4.18

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dictionary comprehensions were added in Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). You're running 2.6. So you need to change this line:

```
indexed_fields = {field: dict(type="string") for field in indexed_fields}
```

Into this:

```
indexed_fields = dict((field, dict(type="string")) for field in indexed_fields)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply...I figured it had something to do with the versioning. Unfortunately RHEL only ships with Python 2.6 (except the new software collections) but I made the changes to the syntax and it all worked flawlessly. Note to self, to deploy on Python27 in prod.

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck on 2.6 in my environment for the exact same reason