# Syntax translation from Python 2.7 to 2.6

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-2.6, wagtail

this is a line from within Wagtail (Django variant CMS with very cool UI). The issue is it's written for Python 2.7 and I am using Python 2.6 with Django + FastCGI on shared hosting.

I've already changed a previous syntax error as spotted [by mhlester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861144/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-when-running-syncdb-on-django)
but can't figure this one out:

```
>>> for attr in json_attrs
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for attr in json_attrs
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the original code:

```
 if use_json: # Return a json response
        if search_results:
            search_results_json = []
            for result in search_results:
                result_specific = result.specific

                search_results_json.append({
                    attr: getattr(result_specific, attr)
                    for attr in json_attrs
                    if hasattr(result_specific, attr)
                })
```

any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no dictionary comprehensions in < Python 2.7. Instead you should pass a `list` of `tuple`s to the `dict()` builtin.

```
dict((attr, getattr(result_specific, attr)) for attr in json_attrs if hasattr(result_specific, attr))
```